# How to change attribute value with pointer

Tags: go

I am trying to change a value within a struct. Unfortunately, the value in "" ==>", flow" doesn't change. I don't understand why.

Can you help me to explain why the pointer doesn't correspond in Slice. May be I must write a slice of pointer ?

Thank you in advance.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Foo struct {
    value float64
}

var flows []Foo;

func AddFoo(foo Foo) {
    flows = append(flows, foo)
}

func UpdateFoo(stream *Foo) {
    stream.value = 5.00
}

func main() {
    x := Foo{1.00}
    AddFoo(x)
    UpdateFoo(&x)
    fmt.Println(x)


    for _, flow := range flows {
        fmt.Println(" ==>", flow)
        }
}
```

Comment: Your `x` got added to the `flows`. Then you change x. This does not change the value inside `flows`. It is like `a := 3; b := a; a = 5; fmt.Println(b);` As `b`'s value is a copy of `a`'s value it would be strange if `b`changed. Same with slices. Work your way through the Tour of Go once more.

Comment: Thank you Volker. It's true. Thank you so much for this help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your function `AddFoo` you are adding a *copy* of Foo to your slice, then in `UpdateFoo` you are changing `x` which is not the same variable as the one in the slice.

Yes, if you'd create a slice of pointers it'd [work](https://play.golang.org/p/WX0YRx-9JG).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to create slice of pointers before my question but I had an error on another function. So Excuse me for this question. I am tired